# Testing fragments that access views of the activity they are embedded into

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-espresso

I want to create a single activity app with multiple fragments and a favorite action button.
Since I need the favorite action button on every fragment, and it should always be in the same position, the button is part of the activities layout. Basically like the "Basic Activity"-Project in Android Studio.

The different fragments set their own onClickListener and thus need to reference the favorite action button, which works fine when running the app.

```
val fab: FloatingActionButton = activity?.findViewById(R.id.fab) 
fab.setOnClickListener { ... }
```

But when doing isolated espresso tests, I obviously get a null pointer exception when the fragment tries to set the onClickListener.

As far as i can see, I now have the following possible solutions for the problem:

1. I could change the production code to make the favorite action button optional, and always check for null before setting the onClick-Listener
2. I could change the test to not test the fragment in isolation but instead with the activity.
3. I test the activity instead of the fragments.

Since my goal is to avoid nullables, solution 2 and 3 appear to be better than solution 1. But solution 1 appears to be the easiest of the three. 
What is the best practice to test fragments in a single activity app that shares some controls via the activity?